Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed (when SQL query included in json)
I've been loading a JSON file to help drive my ETL.  Yesterday I tried to add a SQL query string to this file.  I read it using the following code and get the following error when I attempt to iterate through it:
spark.read.json("path", multiLine=true)

Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column (named _corrupt_record by default)

json excerpt:
  {
        "object_name": "operations",
        "sheet_name": "16A. OPERATIONS",
        "name_list": [
            "operation_id",
            "description",
            "operation_type"
        ],
        "columns": "A:U",
        "null_check": [
            "operation_id",
            "description",
            "operation_type",         
        ],
        "key": "operation_id",
        "header_filter": "operation_id IS NOT NULL",
        "header_select": [
            "operation_id",
            "description",
            "operation_type",
        ],
        "header_output": "operation_header",
        "line_select": [
            "operation_id",
            "line_number",
            "resource_req_schedule_sequence",
            "resource_req_resource_type",
            "resource_req_resource",
        ],
        "line_output": "operation_line",
        "line_query" : "SELECT * FROM table"
    }
]

If I simply attempt to run the SQL query all by itself, it runs fine.  And if I remove the "line_query" SQL line from the JSON (and remove references to it in the code), then the code runs fine.  So presumably just because there are SQL queries in the json is what is causing the issues.
Any idea why or how to fix?

At a glance, your JSON is not well formed. Example: Please remove the comma (,) after the last item operation_type. Similarly, do it for other array items.
"header_select": [
"operation_id",
"description",
"operation_type",
]

use jsonlint.com to validate your JSON
